# Dissolving shapefile but retaining a list of original attribute value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dissolve

How can I dissolve a polygon layer **in QGIS** based on a single attribute but keep all (or some) other attributes at the same time? This is how I want to retain fields:

There are at least two fields I want to retain the information from in the dissolved shapefile, one is a string, the other one is numerical.

I would like to dissolve the shapefile based on the field "Class", and I want to retain the information of columns "Object_ID" and "Signal_species"

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It is now more than one year from your post... From QGIS 2.16, new `Aggregates` functions became available. One of the new expression is `concatenate()`.

**Your Sample**

[image]

**concatenate()**

Open the attribute table and create a new text field (with enough string length), with expression:

```
# Object_ID  -> O_IDs 
concatenate(  "Object_ID" , group_by:= "Class", concatenator:= ', ' )

# Signal_Sp  -> Signals
concatenate( to_string("Signal_Sp"), group_by:= "Class", concatenator:= ', ' )
```

*Please note `concatenate()` takes only texts (strings), so I had to apply `to_string()` to "Signal_Sp" which was integer type...*

After `concatenate()` your attribute table will become like below:

[image]

Now we can dissolve the polygon keeping original attribute data.

[image]

I will need to delete old fields (`Object_ID` and `Signal_Sp`)  afterwards.

Comment: This worked for me but it was extremely slow (almost an hour) to do a concatenation on a table with about 4500 rows. Does anyone have any idea why? It seems like this should be nearly instantaneous to me. QGIS version is 3.10

Comment: @wfgeo Could [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287713/84455) be of help?